# Are these batteries compatible?

Tags: battery

Can you please tell me if a battery with these specs `10.8V, 4400mAh, 47Wh` is compatible with 
these `14.4V, 4400mAh, 63Wh`

Thanks.

Comment: Are they the exact same size and shape?

Comment: You should not judge battery compatibility based on whether or not they "fit."

Comment: it does fit, but I wanted to know if it fitted specification wise

Comment: I presume what you really want to know is whether they're compatible with your laptop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they are not. See the [EE.SE Question and Answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings) on power supplies for a detailed explanation.